# drupals imagecache module only works with 'default' site?

Tags: php, drupal, module, image-caching

i have multisite setup where imagecache module resides under sites/all. My goal is for every site to have its own imagecache folder filled with requests, belonging to that site; e.g. referencing them by domain1/imagecache/files/thumb_image/photos/bigavatar.jpg.

The photos folder have been uploaded via FTP so drupal basically doesnt know about it (database-wise), but imagecache functions perfectly if the folder is under sites/default/files/photos and referenced by default/imagecache/files/thumb_image/photos/bigavatar.jpg.

Have looked for setting up options - and found that if the upload path is changed for a site, then imagecache would work with it but; For my (JS) store of images, sent to my gallery the store data comes from my own module, ximagegallery. This is how the paths are produced:

```
<?php
/**
 * @param title : visible gallery title
 * @param basename filename base of image
 * @param site current site (commonly guessed from REQUEST_URI but goal is to let this be configurable)
 * @param location path of $basename imagefile underneath sites/$site/
*/
    function ximagegallery_get_object($title, $basename, $site, $location) {
        return array(
             "title" => $title,
             "link" => "{$site}{$location}/{$basename}",
             "screenpath" => "{$site}/imagecache/screen{$location}{$basename}",
             "thumbpath" => "{$site}/imagecache/small_thumb{$location}{$basename}"
        );
    }
    ?>
```

Imagecache only works with the upload-path for the filesystem config, i wish to surpass this and make imagecache respond to any location, say if two sites needs to share a common gallery / imagefolder.

Edit; i figured a solution would be to create another hook_menu, calling the imagecache functions from my derived module - as its allready a dependency, this would be modular enough for the purpose i guess

```
<?php
function ximagegallery_menu() {
        // standard route hook
    $items['ximagegallery/store/%'] = array(
         'title' => 'ximagegallery_GENERATE',
         'page callback' => 'ximagegallery_generate_store',
         'page arguments' => array(1),
         'access callback' => 'ximagegallery_access'
    );
        // one hook for each configured path
        $hooks = get_variable('ximagegallery_folderhooks', array());
        foreach($hooks as $folder) {
           $items['$folder.'/imagecache'] = array(
         'page callback' => 'imagecache_cache',
         'access callback' => '_imagecache_menu_access_public_files',
         'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
           );
       }
} ?>
```

If my folderhooks contains 'domain2/foo/bar', then
this allows using of http://domain.tld/drupal/?q=domain2/foo/bar/imagecache/myimagefolder/galleryid/photo.jpg

Splendid =)

Comment: What is your question? I'm sorry, but I don't get it.

Comment: sites/default/files/photos is fubar, it needs to be sites/domain/files/photos

Comment: Oh, I see. Imagecache doesn't work in a multisite configuration since it works with internal URLs only. Have you tried using [imagecache_external](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_external) to work around this issue?

Comment: thx for heads up, was looking through the hook_menu of those and figured out a solution workaround

Comment: Add it as an answer then :) It'll be useful when someone comes with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function ximagegallery_menu() {
        // standard route hook
    $items['ximagegallery/store/%'] = array(
         'title' => 'ximagegallery_GENERATE',
         'page callback' => 'ximagegallery_generate_store',
         'page arguments' => array(1),
         'access callback' => 'ximagegallery_access'
    );
        // one hook for each configured path
        $hooks = get_variable('ximagegallery_folderhooks', array());
        foreach($hooks as $folder) {
           $items['$folder.'/imagecache'] = array(
         'page callback' => 'imagecache_cache',
         'access callback' => '_imagecache_menu_access_public_files',
         'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
           );
       }
} ?>
```